# How do I get only the name of a link without the file extension?

Tags: jquery, substring

How do I get only the name of a link, e.g. "test" from "test.php"?

I'm trying to set up a variable:

```
var linkname= this.href.substring(2);
```

I don't know how `substring()` really works. Is this a kind of the right approach?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

```
$(".nav").delegate("a", "click",function () {
  var linkname = this.href.substr( 0, ( this.href.length - '.php'.length ) );
  $("#claim"+linkname).fadeIn('slow').siblings().hide();
 });
```

First, thanks for the answer. But did I put in something wrong? This still doesn't work.

Maybe my fault: I need to remove a "#" at the beginning too.

**UPDATE THREE**

This the the complete code I'm working on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#claimone, #claimtwo, #claimthree").hide();

$("#claimone").show();

$(".nav").delegate("a", "click",function () {

    var linkname = this.href.substr( 0, ( this.href.length - '.php'.length ) );

    $("#claim"+linkname).fadeIn('slow').siblings().hide();

   });
});
```

The second function generates "#link.php". So I don't know if it doesn't collidate. All claims are in the index.php. By every new loaded content I want also to change the content. The links are like href="one.php", href="two.php", href="three.php".

```
$(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#maincontent-wrapper"),
        $pageWrap    = $("#wrapper"),
        baseHeight   = 0,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $(".nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent
                .find(".maincontent")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " .maincontent", function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $(".nav a").removeClass("active");
                        $(".nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("active");
                    });
                });
        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

This is not an real solution, but it works. I just gave every href a .link class and a name for each claim.

```
$(".link").click(function () {  
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#claim"+divname).fadeIn(200).siblings().hide();
});
```

But that's exactly not what I wanted. Too much code. And now it's not synchron to the loaded 
content fade in. Would be better to combine both fadeins somehow.

**FINAL SOLUTION**

Far away form the first idea of solving this I managed it to bind it to the function it should have actually work with:

```
$claim
        .find("#claim")
                 .fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $claim.show().load(newHash + " #claim", function() {
                        $claim.hide().fadeIn(200);
   });
                });
```

Thanks everyone. Learned a bit more about subtrings beside!

Comment: what you mean by name . are meaning name attr or text between a tags."without ending " give the example what u asking

Comment: I simply want to remove ".php" from "test.php" I don't know what this is exactly called.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". It's not clear what you are trying to do. `this.href` is more likely "http://example.com/test.php" so `"#claim"+linkname` will be "#claimhttp://example.com/test". Use `console.log(this.href)` and `console.log(linkname)` with a modern browser to get an idea of what's going on.

Comment: Read http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Comment: my href is "href=test.php". so I simply want to remove ".php". but since the href is modified before to "#test.php" I now need to remove "#" and ".php". It works when I rewrite the href before but it's not efficiant since some other codes need still the original link.

Answer (score 1):

```
var linkname = this.href.substr( '#'.length, ( this.href.length - '.php'.length ) );
```

'#' or '.php' can be altered to remove whatever you like from the beginning or the end of any string.

Comment: Only handles `.php` and is more erroneous if the extension is `.xdoc` or no extension at all as it will remove not enough or too many characters.

Comment: added this one, but still didn't work. updated my question. maybe it's my fault?

Comment: ok, sorry. now my final update. I need to remove a "#" also from the beginning.

Comment: @Cixate you are correct. But the question explicitly asked about removing '.php' not about removing extensions in general. Personally when it comes to string manipulation I would rather a simple statement, and one where I can see what is being removed (more readable and maintainable) which is why I put '.php'.length. Not that its invalid to write a universal extension remover function. Just not appropriate for this answer.

Comment: @Melros this is easy manipulated to remove anything from the front or the back in a readable way. I have edited my answer to demonstrate removing the hash from the front.

Comment: thank you a lot for the quick reply. but my function is still not running. I guess I'm doing something wrong on another hand.

Comment: Naming the function `get_filename` is very readable and maintainable :). Having to update your code when you find out some of your links are `.foo` instead of `.php` is not, DRY wins for me. However, I agree about clarity of what you are removing and the OP seems to think that exact is better than re-usable so I'll remove the down-vote.

Comment: @Cixate DRY is the light and the way :) however assuming a second usage is not.

Comment: can you give a little more information the code you are writing?

Comment: I updated the Question. Would be so nice if you know what's wrong here.

Comment: is 
newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1); the line in question?

Comment: hmm I would pull from the jquery object like this $(this).attr('href') instead of this.href. Are you sure this.href is working?

Answer (score 0):

```
var linkname;
if ( this.href.indexOf('.') != -1 ) {
    linkname = this.href.substr(0, this.href.lastIndexOf('.'));
}
else {
    linkname = this.href;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a file extension from the end of a filename with this regular expression:

```
var url = this.href;   // test.php
url = url.replace(/\.[^\.\/]*$/, "");
alert(url);    // "test"
```

This will remove the characters from the last period to the end of the string and it will only do so in the last path element so you will get these results:

```
foo/test.php    ==> foo/test
test.php        ==> test
foo.x/test.php  ==> foo.x/test
foo.x/test      ==> foo.x/test
test.           ==> test
test            ==> test
```

Structurally, this regular expression is as follows:

```
a period 
followed by zero or more characters that is not a period and is not a slash 
up until the end of the string
```

You may also want to know that retrieving the `href` attribute for an `<a>` tag will retrieve a fully qualified URL regardless of what was in the original tag that starts with `http://` or `https://` and includes the domain and path.  If you want to get only what was actually specified in the tag, you can use `this.getAttribute('href')` instead of `this.href`.